# Swift imageview frame is equal to image original size

Tags: swift, imageview, frame

when creating an UIImageView with an Image, the view's frame is set to the image's original size. I would like to know it's actual size after all anchor constraints have been applied

I've tried different images and they all do the same thing.

The class with the issues is: SuggestionCloud;
I will explain the issue in three parts:

FIRST: the superclass that sets up all UI elements and invokes the "faulty' custom UIImage class (SuggestionCloud).

SECOND: The suggesionCloud Class

UIScaleControllerVew

```
Class UIScaleControllerView: UIViewController: {


 let suggestionCloud : SuggenstionCloud = {        
    let cloud =  SuggenstionCloud(image: UIImage(named: "suggestionCloud.png"))
    cloud.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return cloud;
}();



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("UIScaleController_DidLoad")
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "8ED7F5")
    view.addSubview(weigtImageView)
    view.addSubview(textView)
    view.addSubview(bottomMenu);
    view.addSubview(suggestionCloud)
    setUpLayout()
    suggestionCloud.setLabels(weightedTags: stuff, selectedTags: selected)
}
extension UIScaleControllerVew {

func setUpLayout() {

    // SuggestionCloud
    suggestionCloud.setConstraints(
        topAnchor: textView.bottomAnchor, topConstant: 0,
        bottomAnchor: bottomMenu.topAnchor, bottomConstant: 0,
        trailingAnchor: view.trailingAnchor, trailingConstant: 10,
        leadingAnchor: view.leadingAnchor, leadingConstant: 10 
//all UI elements are setup underneath..took those out for th
```

The suggestionCloud Class:

import UIKit

class SuggenstionCloud: UIImageView {

```
override init(image: UIImage?) {
    super.init(image: image)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


public func setConstraints(
    topAnchor : NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor>, topConstant: CGFloat,
    bottomAnchor: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor>, bottomConstant: CGFloat,
    trailingAnchor: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>, trailingConstant: CGFloat,
    leadingAnchor: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>, leadingConstant: CGFloat)
{
    self.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: topConstant).isActive = true;
    self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: bottomConstant).isActive = true;
    self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: trailingConstant).isActive = true;
    self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  leadingAnchor, constant: leadingConstant).isActive = true;

}

public func setLabels(weightedTags: [String: Int], selectedTags: [String]) {
    let buttons : [UIButton] = createButtons(weightedTags: weightedTags);
    createLayout(buttons: buttons)
}

private func createButton(buttonText: String) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle(buttonText, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 20.0)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    self.addSubview(button)
    return button;
}

private func createButtons(weightedTags: [String: Int]) -> [UIButton] {
    var buttons : [UIButton] = [];
    for tag in weightedTags {
        buttons.append(createButton(buttonText: tag.key))
    }
   return buttons;
}


private func createLayout(buttons : [UIButton]) {
    if buttons.count == 0 { return }
    let leftEdgePadding : CGFloat = 30;
    let rightEdgePadding : CGFloat = 30;
    let topPadding : CGFloat = 30;

    let padding : CGFloat = 10;
    let availableHeight : CGFloat = self.frame.height + (-2 * topPadding)
    let availableWidth : CGFloat = self.frame.width + (-2 * padding)
    var i = 0;

    var totalHeight : CGFloat = 0;
    var rowLength : CGFloat = 0;
    var rowCount : Int = 0;
    var lastButton : UIButton!


    for button in buttons {
        if totalHeight > availableHeight {print("Cloud out of space"); return}

        if rowLength == 0 && rowCount == 0
        {
            setFirstConstraints(button: button, padding: topPadding)
            totalHeight = button.intrinsicContentSize.height + topPadding;
            rowLength += button.intrinsicContentSize.width + padding
            lastButton = button;

        }
        else if rowLength + button.intrinsicContentSize.width < availableWidth
        {
            setConstraints(button, padding, topPadding, lastButton, rowCount)
            rowLength += button.intrinsicContentSize.width + padding;
            lastButton = button;
        }
        else
        {
            totalHeight += button.intrinsicContentSize.height + padding
            setNewRowConstraint(button: button, padding: padding, totalHeight: totalHeight)
            rowLength = 0;
            rowCount += 1
            lastButton = button
        }
        i += 1;
    }

}
private func setNewRowConstraint(
    button: UIButton,
    padding: CGFloat,
    totalHeight: CGFloat)
{
    let totalPadding = button.intrinsicContentSize.height + padding + totalHeight
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: totalHeight).isActive = true
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
}
private func setConstraints (
        _ button : UIButton,
        _ leftPadding: CGFloat,
        _ topPadding: CGFloat ,
        _ lastButton: UIButton,
        _ rows: Int)
{
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastButton.trailingAnchor, constant: leftPadding).isActive = true
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: topPadding).isActive = true
}
private func setFirstConstraints(button: UIButton, padding: CGFloat)
{
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: padding ).isActive = true
}
```

}

THIRD: finally the issue: 
I'm creating buttons dynamically to fit inside the view.
I have to set each buttion's anchors programmatically to fit their supeclass's . dimensions dynamically.

However: Inside my algorithm self.frame.size is : 800,800 : the original image size upon init().

```
    let availableHeight : CGFloat = self.frame.height // = 800
    let availableWidth : CGFloat = self.frame.width // 800 no bueno
```

The weird this is that the actual size of the UIView is correct in the  Simulator. So the contraints work, but the Image view is not aware of it's actual dimensions

Could anyone help me figure this one out? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When are you reading the incorrect frame?

Comment: IIRC, the frame won't reflect the constraints until viewDidLayoutSubviews is called

Comment: I call it after the class has been initialized. I will edit my quetsion to show the entire class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set labels is being called too soon. The frame isn't set by the time viewDidLoad is called. You need to wait until after viewDidLayoutSubviews/layoutSubviews. Using a flag and doing the set up in didLayoutSubviews should allow you to read the frame properly.

```
var didSetUpSuggestionCloud = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   print("UIScaleController_DidLoad")
   view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "8ED7F5")
   view.addSubview(weigtImageView)
   view.addSubview(textView)
   view.addSubview(bottomMenu);
   view.addSubview(suggestionCloud)
   setUpLayout()
   //make sure suggestionClouds setConstraints is called here
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   guard !self.didSetUpSuggestionCloud else {
      return
   }
   suggestionCloud.setLabels(weightedTags: stuff, selectedTags: selected)
   self.didSetUpSuggestionCloud = true
}
```

A flag is necessary because viewDidLayoutSubviews can be called multiple times throughout a view controllers lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks so much!! That was it!